# Method to embed another website into my website

Tags: jquery, html, external

I need to embed an external website into my website (so i can have a navigation sidebar with hyber links to navigate through other websites)

Methods i have tried:

```
<object data="www.facebook.com" width="100%" height="100%">
      <embed src="www.facebook.com" width="100%" height="100%"> </embed>
      Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.
    </object>
```

and

```
$( "#result" ).load( "http://www.facebook.com", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." )
```

and

```
<iframe id="theFrame" src="http://www.youtube.com" style="width:100%;" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

all i got is

> *website* refused to connect

or blank pages.

Comment: Please give more information

Comment: @executable Edited

Answer (score 2):

Facebook prevents you from linking directly to the actual site via iframe.

There is no way around this. It is built in to the browsers themselves to send some information along in the request header that says it is being requested to be put in frame.

Youtube and other sites also do this as well.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the embed (in the share option) for youtube video to be embed in your website. Similarly you need to check the Facebook developers site to see how the embed works here.

Comment: You are using facebook as an example , which made it look like you are embedding the same...